# input.regex in Hive

Tags: regex, hive, expression, cloudera

A question was asked earlier for the given dataset.

```
03-24-2014  fm506   TOTAL-PROCESS   OK;HARD;1;PROCS OK: 717 processes
03-24-2014  fm504   CHECK-LOAD  OK;SOFT;2;OK - load average: 54.61, 56.95
```

The input regex provided in that thread is not at all working hence I created two "input regex" and tested the first regex in "http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html". The groups are perfect. But when I am trying in Hive, it's loading only NULL values.

input regex I provided as below

```js
([^ ]*)\t+([^ ]*)\t+([^ ]*)\t+([^ ]*)
```

My second input regex is

```js
^(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)\\t+(\\S+)$
```

I thought it will work but it's also not loading NULL values.

Could you please let me know what's wrong with these two input regex?

Comment: Thanks, it worked.!! Could you please also check what's wrong with the other input regex?

Comment: Wiktor Stribizwe, There is no option to accept it. Your answer came in the comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first pattern does not match the entire string, and field matching parts are `[^ ]*`, that is, any 0+ chars other than a space, so the last field cannot be matched (it contains spaces).

The second regex also contains `\S+` patterns matching 1 or more chars other than whitespace,  and the last one does not match the last field.

You may use

```
^(\S+)\t+(\S+)\t+(\S+)\t+(.+)
^([^\t]*)\t+([^\t]*)\t+([^\t]*)\t+(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8Izr3X/1/)

The `[^\t]*` matches any field in a tab-delimited text since it matches zero or more chars other than a tab.

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew, thank you..!! It worked with double slashes (\\).

Comment: @Onlydocs Yes, when you define the regex pattern inside a string literal (inside the code itself), you must make sure backslashes are literal backslashes, and since a backslash is used to form string escape sequences in these literals (like `\n` for newline, `\r` for carriage return, etc.) it is necessary to escape a ``\`` with the second ``\`` to define a literal ``\``. The regex pattern is `^(\S+)\t+(\S+)\t+(\S+)\t+(.+)`, but how it is represented inside code always depends on what kind of string literal, environment, was used to define the pattern text.